# Understanding exponential decay

Tags: integration, derivatives, exponential-function

Say I have a variable $x$ that decays over time $t$ as follows:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{-x}{\tau}.
$$

Solving for $x$, I get

\begin{align}
x &= \frac{-1}{\tau}\int x dt\\
&=e^{-t/\tau}.
\end{align}

My question is so simple I'm embarrassed to be asking it:

Can someone walk me through why

$$x=\frac{-1}{\tau}\int x dt$$

implies

$$x=e^{-t/\tau}?$$

I know this is correct, and know I've thought through the solution in the past, but now have no idea how to think through this correctly.

Comment: do you know how to integrate $\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}$ ? integrate both sides of $\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)} = -1/\tau$ (rigorously we suppose that $x(t) \ne 0$ for some $t$, we deduce that $x(t) \ne 0$ on $[a,b]$, and we write that if $f(t) = g(t)$ for every $ t \in [a,b]$ and $g(t)$ is continuous, then there exists $C$ such that $\int_d^t f(u) du = C + \int_d^t g(u) du$ for every $d,t \in [a,b]$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that using the Laplace transform is the easiest way for me to solve this.  (That, I now remember, is what I used in the past.)

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{-x}{\tau}\\
-x(0) + sx_L &= \frac{-x_L}{\tau}\\
x_L(s+1/\tau)&=x(0)\\
x_L &= \frac{x(0)}{s + 1/\tau}\\
x&=x(0)e^{-t/\tau}.
\end{align}

Note the presence of the initial value of $x$ in the final answer, something I had overlooked in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to integrate via separation of variables. So,

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{x}{\tau}$

$\dfrac{dx}{x}=-\dfrac{dt}{\tau}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \int\dfrac{dx}{x}=-\int\dfrac{dt}{\tau} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \ln(x)=-\dfrac{t}{\tau}$

Thus, $e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}=x$

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful.  i guess my one complaint is that you kick the can down the road a bit: this answer begs the question, how does one derive $ln(x)=\int 1/x dx$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x }{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{-x}{\tau }$$
Seperate Variables
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x }x=\frac{\mathrm{d}t }{-\tau}$$
Integrate both sides
$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x }x=\int \frac{\mathrm{d}t }{-\tau}$$
Antiderivative:
$$\ln \left | x \right |= \frac{-t}{\tau} + c_{1}$$
Solve for Variable
$$\left | x \right |=e^{(-t/\tau)+c_{1}}$$
$$\left | x \right |=e^{(c_{1})}e^{(-t/\tau)}$$
$$\left | x \right |=c_{2}e^{(-t/\tau)}$$
$$x=\pm c_{2}e^{(-t/\tau)}$$

Comment: nice.  it was this answer that helped me get to my answer.  note that given this is a physical system that evolves over time starting at a time zero, $ c_2=x(0)$ -- as shown in my answer.